# Data extraction with pandas or lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

(Full disclosure - relative beginner with Python programming AND Pandas, however, am able to pick up things quickly and absolutely LOVE playing with / manipulating data to get what I want!)

Hey there all - hope all is good with everybody.

That said, I am working on a problem where I have a sample data CSV file that I have imported from the web into my code using pandas and it works awesome..........freakin' AWESOME!

sample code for those that are learning also AFTER installing Pandas:

```py
empCSV = pd.read_csv("https://data........")
print (empCSV)
```

sample output when printed:

```
       Work Date    Employee hours   Overtime Hours
0     02/22/2023  11 19 39 44 65 07         2.0
1     02/20/2023  03 17 26 38 54 15         3.0
2     02/18/2023  08 21 31 32 37 23         4.0
3     02/15/2023  31 32 54 60 63 12         4.0
4     02/13/2023  17 26 37 61 65 02         2.0
etc.....
```

Now, the primary data that i'd like to mess with (given the amount and frequency) is Employee hours. These are where the questions come in. Being that I want to toy with those numbers, should I just filter those by list THEN play with them? So, in reading across several forums, it says that I can extract just those values and then put them all into a list...which I did.....and THAT works. Awesome again!

sample code

```py
empHours = empCSV['Employee hours'].tolist()
print(empHours)
```

sample output when printed:

```
[1435 rows x 3 columns]
['11 19 39 44 65 07', '03 17 26 38 54 15', '08 21 31 32 37 23', '31 32 54 60 63 12', '17 26 37 61 65 02', ......
```

But now, I'd like to get ALL of the first number values (i.e. 11,03,08,...etc), all of the second number values (i.e. 19,17,21,etc...) and so on into individual strings so that I use them as I need to.

Should I stick with Pandas? Should I just use lists & manipulations with loops? Am I way off track?

.....and GO!

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [NumPy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html), you could split up the string lists and construct a 2D array, which can be indexed by column.

#### Constructing a 2D Numpy array

Assuming the sample of the `'Employee Hours'` column:

```
      Employee Hours
0  11 19 39 44 65 07
1  03 17 26 38 54 15
2  08 21 31 32 37 23
3  31 32 54 60 63 12
4  17 26 37 61 65 02
```

The following code can be used to construct the 2D array:

```py
import numpy as np

# 1) Create a list consisting of each employee hours string
empHours = empCSV['Employee hours'].tolist()

# 2) Create a list of lists containing each hours string split up to form a proper list
hoursList = []
for hoursStr in empHours:
    hoursList.append(hoursStr.split())

hours2DArray = np.array(hoursList) 
# Alternatively: hoursArray = np.array([hoursStr.split() for hoursStr in empHours])

print(hours2DArray)
```

Output:

```
[['11' '19' '39' '44' '65' '07']
 ['03' '17' '26' '38' '54' '15']
 ['08' '21' '31' '32' '37' '23']
 ['31' '32' '54' '60' '63' '12']
 ['17' '26' '37' '61' '65' '02']]
```

#### Indexing by column

To extract the entire `n`-th column (to get the `n`-th number value of each row), write `hours2DArray[:, n-1]`.

For example,

```py
# Output the second column
print(hours2DArray[:, 1])
```

Output:

```
['19' '17' '21' '32' '26']
```

#### Transposing a 2D array

It may be more convenient to instead have the rows as columns. This can be accomplished with the [`.transpose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) method:

```py
# Transpose the 2D array to switch the row and column positions.
hours2DArrayTr = hours2DArray.transpose()

print(hours2DArrayTr)

print("\nFourth number values:", hours2DArrayTr[3])
```

Output:

```
[['11' '03' '08' '31' '17']
 ['19' '17' '21' '32' '26']
 ['39' '26' '31' '54' '37']
 ['44' '38' '32' '60' '61']
 ['65' '54' '37' '63' '65']
 ['07' '15' '23' '12' '02']]

Fourth number values: ['44' '38' '32' '60' '61']
```